# Why does Yup validation not work when using both number().positive() and number().moreThan()?

Tags: reactjs, yup

Based on my issue's title, it may seem similar to the one posted [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/354); however, the context is different. In my situation, I have two number fields (*i.e.*, `Min` and a `Max`). The `Min` value has to be a non-zero, positive number and less than the `Max` value (if there is a `Max` value). The `Max` value has to be a non-zero, positive number and greater than the `Min` value (if there is a `Min` value). I have error messages that are supposed to display depending on whether those conditions aren't met when a user tries to submit a form; however, it appears that the order matters in determining when an error message is displayed. For example, if I input `-5` as the `Min` value and `-2` as the `Max` value, only the error message for the `Min` value is displayed, even though the `Max` value violates the "non-zero" rule.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could suggest any workarounds, if there are any. I've included my code below:

```
maxValue: Yup.number().when(['minValue'], {
    is: (minValue) => Boolean(minValue),
    otherwise: Yup.number().positive().nullable(),
    then: Yup.number().positive().moreThan(Yup.ref('minValue)).nullable(),
}),
minValue: Yup.number().when(['maxValue'], {
    is: (maxValue) => Boolean(maxValue),
    otherwise: Yup.number().positive().nullable(),
    then: Yup.number().positive().lessThan(Yup.ref('maxValue)).nullable(),
}),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by swapping out the `.positive()` in my `then` chain for `maxValue` and replacing it with `.test('greaterThanZero', 'Value must be greater than zero', value => value ? value > 0 : ' ')`.